# I tried to compile and build the project , but an error occur requires support-v4:23.4.0. library and Gradle failed to install automatically?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.2

Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0.

Required by:
    familia:app:unspecified
    familia:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
    familia:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:23.3.0
    familia:app:unspecified > com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0 > com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.3.0
    familia:app:unspecified > com.android.support:design:23.3.0 > com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0

I tried Gradle auto synchronization on Android Studio but in vain

the following dependencies added:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.github.zzz40500:AndroidSweetSheet:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
```

Comment: This question needs to be more specific. What is your code? Were you importing something in it, and if so, where?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: The strange thing to me, that I make a compile and build successfully, then with no more coding the error occured

Comment: @MohammedAlAkhras, same issue here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dears,
I launch update from android studio:
Help -> Check for Update...
And Installed API level 23 Revision 3

Then the project compiles as normal.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the suggestion above did not work for me. What I did was to run the Clean and Rerun'app'. The option can be found under Run -> Clean and Rerun'app'.